# Using Cron to restart a systemd user service

Tags: systemd, cron

I have created a --user service in systemd such that a non privileged user can manage a service. This works well.
I wanted to restart the service at a fixed given time of day, so i created a cron job in the users crontab.

Strangely this does not work. The user can restart the service if they run:

```
systemctl --user restart myservice.service
```

However running this from the crontab does not restart the service. Does anyone know why?

This is running on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Please paste output of command `crontab -l`. You have to execute it as user which have permissions to this service. The other question is: why do you want to restart it using cron?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`systemctl --user` needs to talk to the D-Bus session, which involves setting at least `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` and perhaps `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`; typically:

```
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u)
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/bus
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
systemctl --user restart myservice.service
```

You might want to look at systemd timers instead of cron for this.

Comment: This worked. Thanks.
Is there a reason why cron should not be used in this case?

Comment: No particular reason, I only suggested timers because they should deal with all this transparently (but I haven’t used timers for user services so I don’t *know* how to do it and whether it would work).

Comment: There is a reason with respect to the larger point made in a question comment.  Often in my experience this sort of scheduled externally forced restart is a bodge, that papers over an underlying problem.

Comment: systemd user services only run while there is a user session, whereas the cronjob would probably still run if there’s no user session. (That’s why the cronjob doesn’t know about the dbus session: cron exists outside of the session.) I agree that a systemd timer is the better solution here.

Comment: Starting/stopping a service with a timer does not work though, since as soon as the timer triggers all you get is an infinite restart loop of said service.

Answer (score -1):

Same issue.

Adding ;
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u)
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/bus
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS XDG_RUNTIME_DIR

In Lubuntu 22.04 fixed the issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).